# Java. IO. Ввод-вывод через InputStream

Tags: java, input, io, try-catch

У меня такое задание:

Реализовать сервис
boolean isNumber(InputStream in);
метод должен проверить. что в байтовом потоке записано четное число.
Все потоки должны быть обернуты через try-resources. Даже, если это ByteArrayInputStream

Помогите решить.

Comment: А Вы хоть что-то попытались сделать? Мы можем подсказать, помочь, навести на мысль. А так получается что Вы за готовым решением пришли.

Comment: Да к сожалению мой вариант совсем не приняли, так что я даже писать его здесь не стал что-бы не получились вариации на то что в основании не нужно... Вот такой ответ по коду.
1. удали весь код по этому заданию. тебе надо inputstream зачитать в строку. 
2. строку перевернуть в Integer.parseInt
3. И проверить четность.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так?

```
private boolean isNumber(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] number = new byte[4];//Массив с размером 4 байта (т.к. int = 4 байта)
            inputStream.read(number);//Читаем 4 байта в массив
            ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(number);//Врапаем в байт буффер
            int numberInIS = bb.getInt();//Получаем число
            if (numberInIS % 2 == 0)//проверяем на четность
            {
                System.out.println("[isNumber]: number = "+numberInIS+"; is true");
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("[isNumber]: number = "+numberInIS+"; is false");
                return false;
            }
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();//не удалось считать из inputStream
            throw new IOException("Can't read from "+inputStream);
        } finally
        {
            inputStream.close();//закрываем поток
        }
    }
```

Если приходит четное число, например, число 128, то вывод такой и возвращает `true`:

```
[isNumber]: number = 128; is true
```

Если приходит нечетное число, например 821, то возвращает `false`:

```
[isNumber]: number = 821; is false
```